# Combine duplicate rows and sum the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, duplicates

I have the following arrays, they are already sorted:

```py
day =   [5,5,5,6,6,   6,   6,7,7,7,   8,   8,8];
time =  [0,0,0,0,0,1.03,0.28,0,0,0,0.63,5.58,1];
class = [ , , , , ,   b,   b, , , ,   c,   b,c];
```

I want to eliminate the duplicate values in the day array and add the respective value in the time array, but only for the respective class, or zero if class is empty, it would be something like this:

```py
day_fix = [5,   6,7,   8];
class_b = [0,1.31,0,5.58];
class_c = [0,   0,0,1.63];
```

thanks.

Comment: You may get more help if you attempt some code yourself and post it with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following might help you a bit:

```js
const day   = [5,5,5,6,6,   6,   6,7,7,7,   8,   8,  8]
const time  = [0,0,0,0,0,1.03,0.28,0,0,0,0.63,5.58,  1]
const clazz = [ , , , , , 'b', 'b', , , , 'c', 'b','c']

const resultDays = {}

day.forEach((d, i) => {
  resultDays[d] = resultDays[d] || {}
  if (clazz[i]) {
    resultDays[d][clazz[i]] = (resultDays[d][clazz[i]] || 0) + time[i]
  }
})

console.log(resultDays)
```

The output is an object which is just another representation of the result you provided. That way it would be much easier because it eliminates the need for creating separate arrays for each class in future.

Comment: Thanks you, it help me a lot. Im a bit newbie using javascript and I dont know too much about objects, but I will try to convert it to an array, its easier for me to keep running my code. Really thanks you too much!